# Why doesn't the second part of this loop work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The user should insert a name as an input and then confirm with a yes or no (or any of its derivatives) if the 3 worded name includes a middle name or not. So far, I've gotten the loop to work if the answer is yes; however it keeps looping the question if the answer is no.

The purpose: if the answer is yes, the program will understand its a 3 worded name with a middle name and therefore execute naming combinations with the middle name; if its no, the program will understand its a 3 worded name with a second last name instead of a middle name and therefore execute naming combinations accordingly.

Please note I have exluded a lot of the code for sharing purposes.

What I'm I doing wrong? My question is in regards to the elif part of the loop.

```
print ('enter name')
providedname = input ()
while providedname != 'quit':
  if len(providedname.split())==4:
    pass

  elif len(providedname.split())==3:
    print ('Does the name include a middle name or middle initial? Please type yes or no:')
    userinput = input()

    if userinput.startswith ('ye' or 'Ye' or 'YE' or 'ya' or 'Ya' or 'YA'):
      firstname, middlename, lastname = providedname.split()

    elif userinput.startswith ('no' or 'No' or 'NO' or 'na' or 'Na' or 'NA'):
      firstname, lastname, secondlastname = providedname.split()

    else:
      pass

  print ('enter name or type quit or q to exit')
  providedname=input()
  continue
```

Comment: That code isn't syntactically valid. Also it's only indented with single spaces, making it very hard to read. Give a [mcve] that **actually recreates the issue**.

Comment: Tip: `if userinput[:2].lower() in {'ye', 'ya'}:`

Comment: Thanks jon, its a long code, so I had to strip it down. I have added double spaces as indentation to make it easier to read. I've also added how I intend to split the three worded name input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just run this in the interpreter

```
>>> 'ye' or 'Ye' or 'YE' or 'ya' or 'Ya' or 'YA'
'ye'
```

Your `startswith` isn't working the way you think it does.

Other than that, you can shorten that statement up if you lowercase your strings.

Runnable example

```
while True:
  providedname = input ('enter name or type quit or q to exit: ')

  if providedname in {'quit', 'q'}:
    break

  names = providedname.split()

  if len(names) == 4:
    pass
  elif len(names) == 3:
    userinput = input('Does the name include a middle name or middle initial? Please type yes or no:')

    if userinput[:2].lower() in {'ye', 'ya'}:
      firstname, middlename, lastname = names
    elif userinput[:2].lower() in {'no' , 'na'}:
      firstname, lastname, secondlastname = names
    else:
      pass

    print(firstname, lastname)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @cricket_007 , I ran it through the interpreter and realized I had completely misunderstood the `or` and the `startswith`. Your solution is on point and really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `or` like that. It makes sense in English, but it doesn't work in Python. One way to express what you're doing is with a mini `for` loop along with the `any` function, like so:

```
if any(userinput.startswith(string) for string in ['ye', 'Ye', 'YE', 'ya', 'Ya', 'YA']):
```

It reads almost like English if you shuffle the word order around a bit:

> If the user input starts with any of the strings in this list...

Even better is to lowercase the input string first. Then you don't have to check so many combinations.

```
userinput = input().casefold()    # Python 3.3+
userinput = input().lower()       # Earlier

if any(userinput.startswith(string) for string in ['ye', 'ya']):
```

As it happens, `startswith` can also accept a list of strings. You can actually ditch the all the `any()` machinery and have simply:

```
if userinput.startswith(('ye', 'ya')):
```

(Thanks to [@kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416467/kindall) for that tip.)

Comment: `startswith()` will take a tuple of alternatives, so you don't need that generator expression. `startswith(("ye", "ya"))` will do ya.

Answer (score 0):

It LOOKS as though you're missing the ending ' on the print command inside your elif ('Does the name include....), causing the rest of it to be taken as more text input. Try adding that ' and see if that helps!

Comment: I presume that's just a typo in the question, not in the OP's actual code.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to type it into my post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could have more complex names, for example, "Oscar De La Hoya", which would skip because the name would have length = 4. Ignoring 'difficult names', the next thing would be to work on cleaning the user's input. I would clean the user's input like so:

```
userinput = input().lower().strip()
```

This way you can make is simpler for yourself and also more readable.

Now you can do:

```
if userinput == 'yes':
    firstname, middlename, lastname = providedname.split()
else:
    firstname, lastname, secondlastname = providedname.split()
```

Finally (as the other answer states), if a 'valid' input is given, you'll want to break out of the while loop with a `break`.

Comment: Thank you @David542, I'm going to read about these solutions to understand them and give them a try. I'm learning Python as I work through this program.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main problems (ignoring all the syntax errors assuming that they are just here on your question but your actual code is OK)

First you are never breaking out of the while loop, you must use the `break` statement anywhere you want to exit the loop.

Second you are overwriting the `providedname` at the end of the loop, that will leave you without the actual name, the variable will be quit even after the correct name was provided.

Comment: Thanks @Dalvenjia, I have never really understood the use of the break statement in practice. I'll give it a try.